# create installer for windows which will install xla add-in onto windows machine for excel application

Tags: windows-installer, excel-addins, xla

I want to create *installer* from the **xla add-in** which i created for windows excel. When I run the installer it should install the add-in for excel application onto targeted machine. Is there any way to achieve the intended task ? How can I make this happen ?

Comment: A trick I used back in the day was to install the add-in directly to [Excel's startup folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/use-startup-folders). Then it used to load the addin on Excel launch (for all users when installed to the shared path). I do not know if this still works properly due to new malware countermeasures and other technical changes, but maybe give it a try? There are also (or used to be) per-user keys in the registry (HKCU) where you can allow an add-in to be enabled and disabled as well as registered (helping performance if you have many add-ins).

Comment: Just to clarify, with the HKCU keys you can disable the add-in from loading by user selection, thereby preventing resource hogs from loading. It is much harder to deploy per-user settings with MSI than shared settings.

Comment: Probably, this is what you're looking for: https://www.itninja.com/question/automated-excel-add-ins